# Не могу подключить namespace используя autoload

Tags: php, namespace

Класс `Autoload.php` подключает в проект все имеющиеся .php-файлы. Не могу использовать пространство имен какого-либо файла, если он подключен через Autoload.

Ручное подключение файла (*используя `require`/`include`*) и подключение его [`namespace`](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.php) работает без ошибок.

Autoload.php:

```
<?php

/** 
 * Подключает все имеющиеся файлы в папках $array_paths[]
 */

function __autoload($class_name)
{
    $array_paths = array(
        '/models/',
        '/components/',
        '/controllers/',
    );

    foreach ($array_paths as $path) {
        $path = ROOT . $path . $class_name . '.php';

        if (is_file($path)) {
            include_once $path;
        }
    }
}
```

Authorize.php:

```
<?php
//require_once 'Admin.php';
use Admin\Auth as Auth;

class Authorize 
{
    public function actionAuth()
    {
        Auth::checkLogin();
    }
}
```

Admin.php:

```
<?php
namespace Admin;

class Auth
{
    public static function checkLogin()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

При взаимодействии с классом Auth выводит:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Admin\Auth' not found in path\Authorize.php on line 10
```

---

Возможно, я не понимаю, как работает Autoload, но почему я могу получить доступ ко всем файлам, а использовать их namespace не могу? (PHP 5.6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас `$class_name` передается как полное имя класса вместе с пространством имен.

И вот на этом этапе

```
$path = ROOT . $path . $class_name . '.php';
```

у вас получается что-то вроде

```
ROOT.'/models/Admin\\Auth.php'
```

А такого файла у вас скорее всего нет

Comment: И вот что я сделал, исходя из ваших слов: `$class_name = explode('\\', $class_name);`
`$class_name = end($class_name);`. Все заработало. Большое спасибо за наводку.

Answer (score 0):

можно еще так

```
str_replace('\\', '/', __NAMESPACE__);
```

, хотя в вашем случае нужно только короткое имя класса.

Интересно что namespace обязательно должен присутствовать в файле класса, а доступ к нему производится или установкой пространства имен или указанием полного имени класса или имени класса относительно установленного пространства имен.

Ниже загрузчик, код не мой, но я проверял он вполне рабочий. Нужно только загрузить сам загрузчик, выше него естественно указать желаемое пространство имен, и дальше уже работать непосредственно с классами и их функциями.

Загрузчик AutoPSR-4.php

```
<?php
class Autoloader
{
    public static function register()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
            $file = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class).'.php';
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                require $file;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
}
Autoloader::register();
```

Пример обращения к функциям классов в файле index.php

```
<?php
namespace models; //установка пространства имен models
//namespace models\Z; //или глубже
require 'AutoPSR-4.php'; //подключение загрузчика

$my = new A; //расположен в models\A.php
$my->test();
Z\Zed::test(); //расположен в models\Z\Zed.php
\controllers\Xclass::test(); // расположен вне текущего пространства имен в controllers\Xclass.php
```

Пример класса controllers\Xclass.php

```
<?php
namespace controllers;
class Xclass
{
    public function test()
    {
        echo '<br>класс Xclass';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Автозагрузчик composer`a.

Подключение через композер, предполагает запихивание всего апликейшена в папку, связывание с именем проекта, а следовательно все неймспейсы приобрели дополнительный префикс \Проект, и стал выглядеть подобным образом \Проект\сабнеймспейс\класс, т.е. нужно для нормального функционирования, переименовывать во всех файлах проекта пространство имен, внедряя имя проекта, но чтобы не менять в глубинах кода используемые классы, можно добавить указатель на пространство имен use.

Теперь в начале каждого класса пишем используемое пространство имён. У основных классов это:

```
<?php 
namespace Проект;
```

А у контроллеров:

```
<?php 
namespace Проект\Controllers;

<?php
namespace Проект\Controllers;
use Проект\Controller as Controller;
```

Обязательно следует добавить в файл проекта composer.json, связку имени вашего проекта с каталогом где вы его держите.

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "YourGitHubName\\NameProject\\": "public_html/"
        }
}
```

После этого нужно выполнить команду php composer.phar update, чтобы подключились пути автозагрузчика.